# Am using jquery chosen plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

From the dropdown list I want only the some part(for eg. AL_Alabhama means i want only AL). i did this using the split function.When I select some value from dropdown,the text box contains the splitted result but the same value is reflected back to the dropdown list.I want the original value in the dropdown .Please suggest some solutions

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var selText;
            $('#locate option').each(function () {
                $(this).attr('name', $(this).text());
            });
                    $('#locate').change(function () {
             //Gets the value for selected option
                    selText = $('#locate option:selected').text();
              //split the value
                     $('#locate option:selected').text(selText.split("_")[0]).trigger('liszt:updated');
                 //trying to add the values again to the dropdown
                    $('#locate').next().click(function () {
                    if (selText == "") {
                        $("#locate option").filter(":contains(" + selText.split("_")[0] + ")").text(selText).trigger('liszt:updated');

                });
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look at the line `$('#locate option:selected').text(selText.split("_")[0]).trigger('liszt:updated');`

lets separate it into 2 parts for convenience:

```
var splittedText = selText.split("_")[0];
$('#locate option:selected').text(splittedText).trigger('liszt:updated');
```

do you see what happens? instead of assigning the splitted text to a variable, you set it as a text back to the dropdown.

just assign it to a variable like i showed you above: `var splittedText = selText.split("_")[0];`

and remove the part `.text(splittedText)`

so it would look like this:

```
var splittedText = selText.split("_")[0];
$('#locate option:selected').trigger('liszt:updated');
```

**UPDATE:**

triggering the custom event `.trigger('liszt:updated');` will only notify the Chosen plugin that you have updated the dropdownlist. if you want to set the text of the textbox separately, you need to just do it manually:

```
$("#myTextBox").val(splittedText);
```

as you probably know (or dont), the selector `$('#locate option:selected')` will return you a list of all selected `<option>` elements who have a parent with `id="locate"`.

therefore, since most likely you will only have 1 option selected at a time, this will return you the selected option in the dropdownlist.

when you call the function `.text()` of a jquery object and provide arguments (eg: `.text(splittedText)`), it will set the text of every element in that list that the jquery selector returns. 

if you dont want the select options change their text, do not call `.text(splittedText)`

Comment: $('#locate option:selected').trigger('liszt:updated'); This only updates the value in the text box and dropdown.It doesnt take the splitted value in text box

Comment: @JaspherJ of course not, thats what i just said... `var splittedText = selText.split("_")[0];` <---- this takes the splitted value into the variable `splittedText` which you can use later as you see fit

Comment: ('#locate option:selected').text(splittedText).trigger('liszt:updated');

Comment: ('#locate option:selected').text(splittedText).trigger('liszt:updated'); When I execute this i will get the spliited text in text box.My problem is that the same spliited value is again reflected back to the dropdown options which contains only the splitted results leaving the orginal value back

Comment: @JaspherJ you get it all wrong. it is not reflected back to the dropdownlist from the textbox, it is reflected **to the textbox from the dropdownlist**. you set the text of the dropdownlist using `.text()` and then reflect it to the textbox using `.trigger('liszt:updated');` which tells the plugin to update the textbox from the dropdownlist. if you dont want to update the drop downlist, then update the textbox manually and dont call `.trigger('liszt:updated');`. you dont even need the chosen plugin for this action.